# Prevent hardcoding of Static Resource URL

Tags: static-resources, digital-experience

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://xxxx--devi--c.sandbox.vf.force.com/resource/1111111101000/faviconname" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Is there a way to dymanically get the static resource url ?

I am using this tag in the Experience Site > Settings > Advanced > Head Markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a relative URL:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../resource/faviconname" type="image/x-icon" />
```

The numbers in the middle of the URL are only needed if you frequently update your resource. In fact, the number doesn't even matter if you copy it exactly, because any number will return the latest version.

Edit: I should mention that the Site itself still caches the resource, so make sure you Publish your changes to see those changes live on the Site.

Comment: if the site url has a subdomain would he relative url still be the same as mentioned in your solution above. ? I can see the favicon in the developer pro SB's but not in the Partial SB.  Notice the difference in the site url. Partial SB: https://cpcpcpcp--uat.sandbox.my.site.com/something   and  DeveloperPro:  https://cpcpcpcp--qa.sandbox.my.site.com

Comment: @GroundToCloud Those are classic Site URLs? The sites are not working correctly. The newer DE sites redirect to something like `subdomain.force.com/something/s/` or `subdomain.force.com/s/`. You may need to experiment to get the correct URL if it's not doing that. It might just be `/resource/faviconname` or `resource/faviconname`, but it's definitely better to have a partial URL rather than a full canonical URL.

Comment: These are DE site URL's. I added this and it works <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cpfcpfcpf--uat.sandbox.my.site.com/something/resource/faviconname" type="image/x-icon" />  which means  /resource/something/faviconname should work. 
In your response did you mean /resource/faviconname or /resource/something/faviconname

Comment: @GroundToCloud If that code works, then `/something/resource/faviconname` should also work.